# SQL Query (Like) Trying to find Titles with AND

Tags: sql, sql-like

When doing a SQL Query and I want to pull up entries from a table that have AND in the name, but I do not want names that just have and in them.....

Confusing, but I'll show an example

There are 2 Entries in the table:

> - Pandomniam
> - Frank and Beans.

When I do the query I just want Frank and Beans to come up, not Pandomniam.  I am doing something like

```
SELECT NAME FROM TABLE WHERE NAME LIKE '%and%'
```

this will get me results, but I have uneeded ones.

My first instinct is to try and see if I can get just Pandomniam in a result so I could do an AND NOT LIKE to filter them out  but I can't seem to come up with one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about adding a couple spaces:

```
SELECT NAME FROM TABLE WHERE NAME LIKE '% and %'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT NAME FROM TABLE
WHERE
NAME LIKE '% and %' OR 
NAME LIKE 'and %' OR 
NAME LIKE '% and'
```

Comment: this will include "brand " and "andean"

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT NAME FROM TABLE WHERE NAME LIKE '% and %'
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what brand of RDBMS you're using.  MySQL supports a regular-expression predicate `RLIKE` with a metacharacter sequence for "word boundary":

```
SELECT NAME FROM TABLE WHERE NAME RLIKE '[[:<:]]and[[:>:]]'
```

If you're using another brand of database other than MySQL, perhaps you can research its regular expression features.